# How do the parameters in ruby '.each do' for-loops work?

Tags: ruby

What's confusing me in the code below is how the parameters `state` and `abbrev` match up with the keys and and the values of the hash? Or in other words, how is `state` matched up with `'oregon'` and `abbrev` with `'OR'` (if the parameters matched words in the hash, then I could understand that)

Are they matched up correctly because the first parameter is paired with the first value in the code block?

```
states = {
  'Oregon' => 'OR',
  'Florida' => 'FL',
  'California' => 'CA',
  'New York' => 'NY',
  'Michigan' => 'MI'
}

states.each do |state, abbrev|
  puts "#{state} is abbreviated #{abbrev}"
end
```

The output of this code:

```
Oregon is abbreviated OR
Florida is abbreviated FL
California is abbreviated CA
New York is abbreviated NY
Michigan is abbreviated MI
```

Sorry for not being able to put my question across clearly, still new to this :S

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`each` is going through each pair in the hash and then using general terms to describe the pair so that you can write code that will work for everything in your hash.

It might be easier to see what is going on if you look at how it operates on an array.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].each do |num|
  puts "Number is #{num}"
end
```

There are five elements in the above array.  I chose to call them "num" since they are all numbers, but I could have called each specific element "item" or "element" or "poodle" or "potato" or anything you like.  The name inside of the | | bars is really just how you are referring to an individual item inside the array or hash in the block.

Now let's do the same thing with a hash.

```
hash = {
  1 => "one",
  2 => "two",
  3 => "three"
}
hash.each do |item|
  puts "item: #{item}"
end
```

This will output:

```
item: [1, "one"]
item: [2, "two"]
item: [3, "three"]
```

Ideally, we want to be able to work with both the key and the value in a hash when we're iterating through, so you would want to do something more along these lines:

```
hash.each do |key, value|
  puts "key: #{key}, value: #{value}"
end
```

Outputs:

```
key: 1, value: one
key: 2, value: two
key: 3, value: three
```

The `each` method on hashes is essentially `each_pair` (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-each_pair).  That way, Ruby expects that if you give it two variable names, you must be operating on the key and value of each element in the hash.  There are some other helpful methods like `each_key` and `each_value` that you may find interesting as well.

I don't know if that answered your question at all.  Let me know if I can elaborate!

Answer (score 0):

The `each` method iterates over key/value pairs when you're operating on a Hash structure. If you define your block to accept two values, this is how they'll break out.

In this particular case, the key is `state` and the value is `abbrev`, so it all works out.

Comment: "If you define your block to accept two values, this is how they'll break out."

What I'm after is how they break out like this? Is it because `state` will look for the first object in the code block and match up with that? In this case it finds`'Oregon'` so it matches up that with the state parameter?

Comment: It's a function of how calling a block works. If you declare a block that takes one argument you get a key-value pair Array. If you have a block that takes two arguments, you get independent variables. This is much the same in how you can have things like `key, value = method_call` where the result of a method call is expanded into separate variables if you prefer. Block calls and variable assignments are special cases, as regular method calls do not auto expand like this.

Answer (score -3):

```
class Powers
  def initialize(x)
    @x = x
  end

  def each(&block)
    yield 1, @x
    yield 2, @x * @x
    yield 3, @x * @x * @x
  end
end

p = Powers.new(3)
p.each do |n, r|
  puts "#{n} -> #{r}"
end
```

Here is simple demo for you. No explanation needed I think :)